# Integration measure in quantum field theory conventions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions

In my university QFT course the lecturer used a convention for the integration measure with a factor $1/(2E(\vec{k}))$. For instance in $$\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3\vec{k}}{2(2\pi)^3E(\vec{k})}(a^\dagger(\vec{k})e^{ik\cdot x}+a(\vec{k})e^{-ik\cdot x}).$$ The argument was that the factor $1/(2E(\vec{k}))$ makes integrals Lorentz invariant. However, in some books and online resources I've seen factors of $1/(\sqrt{2E(\vec{k})})$ instead. For example in Peskin and Schroeder there's an equation $$\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2E_p}}(a^\dagger_pe^{ip\cdot x}+a_pe^{-ip\cdot x}).$$ As far as I understand this is just a matter of convention. As a consequence of this difference some equations in my lectures and the book are different by appropriate factors and some are the same. My question is what's the benefit of using the square root convention? It doesn't make integrals Lorentz invariant so what's the point of using it? It seems to me like this can only make transformations a bit more complicated.

Comment: They are actually the exact same integrals. It's just that some sources absorb a factor of $\sqrt{2E}$ into the creation and annihilation operators.

Comment: @knzhou Silly me. That makes sense. I was just really confused seeing two seemingly different equations at first. As I was writing this question I realised that other equations are different as well. Somehow it didn't come to me that factors can be absorbed to variables. I feel a bit stupid asking the question now.

Answer (score 1):

The square root convention is identical to the first one, up to a redefinition of the commutation relations of the creation and annihilation operators. The benefit of using the "square root version" is that the commutation relations between the creation and annihilation operators is simply a delta function with no normalization (this, however, is not a Lorentz-invariant formula). Furthermore, the Hamiltonian is quadratic in the field (to zeroth order), and thus the momentum measure in its expression will be Lorentz invariant.